# Dynamic component cannot be loaded with URL on Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix

I have a problem when loading dynamic component at Laravel. The component always loaded from this URL :

http://localhost/js/admin/login.js?id=ba0d9bc8cd7797b0046c

The component should be loaded at this URL:

http://localhost/konsultasi/js/admin/login.js?id=ba0d9bc8cd7797b0046c

I'm not running a Laravel with Artisan Serve, I only change the htaccess file so it can redirect to a public directory.

This is my mix-manifest.json

```
{
    "/js/admin/login.js": "/js/admin/login.js?id=ba0d9bc8cd7797b0046c",
    "/js/vendor.js": "/js/vendor.js",
    "/js/admin/app.js": "/js/admin/app.js",
    "/css/admin.css": "/css/admin.css",
    "/js/admin/adminlte.js": "/js/admin/adminlte.js",
    "/js/manifest.js": "/js/manifest.js"
}
```

and this is how my blade view call the javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Inspektorat | Konsultasi</title>
    <link href="{!! asset('css/admin.css') !!}" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="{!! asset(mix('js/manifest.js')) !!}"></script>
    <script src="{!! asset(mix('js/vendor.js')) !!}"></script>
</head>
<body class="hold-transition login-page">
    <div class="login-box">
        <div class="login-box-body">
            <div class="login-logo">
                <img src="{!! url('img/logo.png') !!}" style="width:50%;">
            </div>
            <div id="app">
                <login></login>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="{!! asset(mix('js/admin/app.js')) !!}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

At this point. I've got this error

```
http://localhost/js/admin/login.js?id=ba0d9bc8cd7797b0046c net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

and

```
vendor.js:11470 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve async component: function Login() {
      return __webpack_require__.e/* import() */(26).then(__webpack_require__.bind(null, 28));
    }
Reason: Error: Loading chunk 26 failed.
```

Comment: I think using virtualhost will solve the problem. Try it.

Comment: I don't use a Virtualhost, but I will try it.

Comment: @RouhollahMazarei now it works with artisan serve, I also have a virtualhost too. but how to make it works like charms on a production environment?

Comment: Virtual host can simulate the production (server) environment. So you don't have to change anything (almost).